# beautifulsoup и page-buttons

Tags: python, beautiful-soup

Как переключать кнопки страниц для парсинга контента через beautifulsoup, если они изменяют html код, а не атрибуты ссылки (по типу 'site.com/news?page=1').

Вот так выглядят элементы на первой странице:

[image: Первая страница сайта]

А вот так на второй:

[image: Вторая страница сайта]

Answer (score 2):

На первой странице найдите в paginator номер последней (так, например):

```
last_page = soup.find_all('div', class_='page-button')[-1].text
```

и делайте поочередно запросы к страницам:

```
for page in range(1, int(last_page)):
    r = request.get(f'site.com/news?page={last_page}')
```

Comment: В том то и дело, что сайт НЕ изменяет url никаким образом после смены страницы. Так же он не перезагружается

Comment: @MemeDownOleg дайте адрес сайта

Comment: жуть... убирайте ссылку )) поищу, похоже, где-то есть js, который насыпает гифки на страницу, пока не нашел

Comment: Ещё раз прошу прощения, спасибо за помощь